# how to find last group on each page in crystal report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I want to show group footer only on last group of every page.
for that I need to find last group on every page so that I can use that in suppress formula.
My report has multiple groups and keep group together checked.

Is there any way to accomplish this ?

Searched it on the web but not found anything useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no way to do that.
But if you explain the reporting scenario, perhaps there's a different way to achieve the objective.

Comment: I want to add note in the group footer on every page only on last group, that's my customer requirements. Now I convinced him not to do this but still what are the other ways ?

Answer (score 0):

Given that the note is not related to the actual group content, the simplest option is to place it in the page footer.